# Table not showing after insertion of Class

Tags: php, html, class, html-table

I want to style the following mysqli output:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $date = $row['name'];
    $comment = $row['id'];
    $amount = $row['icon'];
    echo 
"<tr><td style='width: 600px;'>".$date."</td></tr>
<tr><td style='width: 600px;'>".$comment."</td></tr>
<tr><td>".$amount."</td>
</tr>";
} 

echo "</table>";
```

I want to use for the `<td style='width: 600px;'>` a css class. If I use the following code, my mysql data disappears. Why?

```
<tr><td class="links">".$date."</td></tr>
```

Comment: This is not the complete code. This being in an `echo` and since you aren't really using `"` for the variable, you could change to `echo '<tr><td class="links">'.$date.'</td></tr>;'`. Also, that wouldn't just dissapear. It would probably give you an erro or warning. If you are using even notepadd++, you would be abe to see that the `"links"` part is actually closing the quote from the `echo`

Comment: Where is `<tr><td class="links">".$date."</td></tr>` in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about, or am I saying something weird .. ?

```
<tr><td class='links'>".$date."</td></tr>
```

You need to escape the "", so it won't be interpreted as end of te echo. Use can also use \ to [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) it. My way just solves it by switching the "" from links to ''.

Comment: If he uses "" you can put the variables inside without chains.

Comment: Like this right? @PhiterFernandes

Comment: Actually ,like this:

<tr><td class='links'>$date</td></tr>

Comment: This is getting some votes, please insert more information than the code itself. Explain something... Get my comment, if you will

Comment: @FirstOne Thanks I will update ;-)

Comment: Thats it. Thank you!

Comment: @Hertus Please accept my answer in the left of the screen

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong at

```
<tr><td class="links">".$date."</td></tr>
```

Should be

```
<tr><td class='links'>".$date."</td></tr>
```

If your echo is between quotes `"`,you must put the HTML stuff inside apostrophes `'`.

Also you won't need to chain the variables, since you are using quotes, so you can do it as follows:

```
<tr><td class='links'>$date</td></tr>
```

Here you can see a full text explaining the differences:

[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

conver **THIS**

```
echo 
"<tr><td style='width: 600px;'>".$date."</td></tr>
<tr><td style='width: 600px;'>".$comment."</td></tr>
<tr><td>".$amount."</td>
</tr>";
```

if you start the echo statement with double quotation you need to use single in between like this

convert it **TO**

```
echo "<tr><td class='links'>".$date."</td></tr>"
."<tr><td class='links'>".$comment."</td></tr>"
."<tr><td>".$amount."</td>"
."</tr>";
```

**OR** you could right the html code out of your php code like this

```
?>
<tr><td class='links'><?php echo $date; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td class='links'><?php echo $comment; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td><?php echo $amount; ?></td></tr>
<?php
```

Comment: @FirstOne thanks for mention :) no problem :]